# Provide stubbing for API calls in yeoman generated app

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, stubbing

I've been trying to create api stubs for an app that was generated with `yeoman`. Nothing special here, I just called:

```
mkdir demo1 
cd demo1
yo angular
```

For dev purposes, I need api stubs, and the only module I've found so far that does this is [lineman](https://github.com/testdouble/lineman#stubbing-server-side-endpoints). However, lineman is not, as far as I can tell, very *yeoman-friendly*, so what I did was start lineman on port `8000`, provide some api stubs (like the ones in docs), and added `"grunt-connect-proxy": "~0.1.5"` to project node modules, then created a proxy that wound pass all `localhost:9000/api/*` to `localhost:8000/api/*`, thus providing the stubs.

While this works, I'd like to remove the lineman dependency and provide the stubs myself.  This is the code I've wrote so far (added `express` as dependency for routing/parameter parsing) - most of the code is bits & pieces from express modules, in order to wrap `http.ServerRequest` and `http.ServerResponse` into express `request` & `response`:

```
// load all grunt tasks
require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

var drawRoutes = require('./config/server').drawRoutes;
var express = require('express');
var expressApp = express();
drawRoutes(expressApp);
var router = expressApp._router;

// Provide api stubs through express router functionality.
var apiStubSnippet = function(req, res, next) {
  var match = router.matchRequest(req);
  if (typeof(match) !== 'undefined') {
    // Found a match, invoke it
    if (match.callbacks.length > 0) {

      var _req = require('express/lib/request');
      var _resp = require('express/lib/response');

      // Set the two objects together ... but why?!
      _req.__proto__ = req;
      _req.app = expressApp;
      _req.res = _resp;

      _resp.__proto__ = res;
      _resp.app = expressApp;
      _resp.req = _req;

      match.callbacks[0](_req, _resp);
    }
  } else {
    // No match on the router, go next.
    next();
  }
};
```

At this point, calls *seem to be resolved* (no more errors in console). But, the calls stick to pending and I don't know how to proceed. I'm pretty sure the code is overly complex for what it needs to do, but I'm a beginner with grunt & node modules.

Any help would do, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Angular allows you to stub with `$httpBackend`, have you tried this?

I like breaking JS best practices whenever possible, so here is something I did for a project earlier this year:

```
app.run(function ($httpBackend) {
  var createResponse = function (type, url, status, response) {
    var when = $httpBackend.when(type, url);
    if (angular.isDefined(status) && angular.isDefined(response))
      when.respond(status, response);
    return when;
  };

  String.prototype.get =
  RegExp.prototype.get = function (status, response) { return createResponse('GET', this, status, response); };

  String.prototype.post =
  RegExp.prototype.post = function (status, response) { return createResponse('POST', this, status, response); };

  String.prototype.put =
  RegExp.prototype.put = function (status, response) { return createResponse('PUT', this, status, response); };

  /^\/views\//
    .get()
    .passThrough();

  '/api/login'
    .post(200, {
      // response object.
    });
});
```

This particular approach may not be what you want, however [`$httpBackend`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) probably is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I really want is to _no change any client code_. Of course, you can mock the xhr in either service / controller objects, provide a different service which mimics the real thing (exactly what you do in tests). 

I'm still to find a solution here :). Will post if I fix the issues.

Comment: You only include the $httpBackend module in development. It's designed by Angular for just your purpose. I'm not sure why you would want to go through a lot of trouble further up your stack to produce the same results.

Comment: I'd want to not change a single line of code from client app, but stub the underlying API implementation (i.e. backend). Still not found the solution, but will post here when I solve it (also, if).

Answer (score 0):

The two ports are configured for the same context, try changing to: localhost:9000/* and localhost:8000/api/*  .
These context and ports are configured in Gruntfile?